# using vb6 program that has a System.Collections.ArrayList in a clean Win XP SP2 install

Tags: vb6, windows-xp, activex, ocx

I've written a program in VB6 that uses System.Collections.ArrayList. The program runs fine on a PC with WinxXP SP2 and VB6 installed. On another PC with a fresh Win XP SP2 install, the program craps out with Run Time Error 429, ActiveX component can't create object. This is referring to the System.Collections.ArrayList, as confirmed by removing the System.Collections.ArrayList and the program runs fine on the PC. How do I install/register/? System.Collections.ArrayList onto this PC?

Comment: Why are you writing anything new in VB6?

Comment: How are you using System.Collections.ArrayList in VB6?

Comment: Have you installed the dotnetframework in the winXPSP2-machine?

Comment: Why in the *world* are you using a `System.Collections.ArrayList` in VB 6? That's not a good option in .NET code, it's *certainly* not a good option in VB 6. A standard `Collection` class is just as good ([you can even make it typesafe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177708/vb6-equivalent-to-listsomeclass)), and doesn't require all the superfluous ActiveX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that may work for you: http://www.idautomation.com/kb/activex-component-cant-create-object.html

Comment: I guess you didn't take the time to read the provided link, because it explains how to fix the OP's issue.

Comment: Maybe installing the .Net framework 2 solved the OP's problem. But that link is still 95% irrelevant.