# How to implement custom iterable class in VBA

Tags: excel, class, vba, foreach, iunknown

I want to add a feature to my classes so I can use them in for-each loops.

I wrote hashmaps, arraylists, queues, sets and so on that I want to iterate over.
Now I'm looking for a way to implement the IUnknown class to build custom iterators.

I already know how to use

```
private objPeople as Collection
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
    Set NewEnum = objPeople.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

but all those examples out there are based on the Collection class, which I do not want to use.

What I want to focus on is trying to implement the IUnknown interface, but I haven't found any references on how to do that.

I have vast experience in Java, C++, C# and so on, so I assume that THERE HAS TO BE A WAY to implement that even in VBA, maybe even with API calls stuff like that.

Comment: [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/19379641#19379641) is related. See comments section for links to other references. And I'm sorry but I am not understanding what you are actually trying to implement?

Comment: Yeah they are realted. But nothing that I don't already know. They all get the IUnknown iterator from the Collections class they're using. I want to go one more step and instead of using Collection in my code, I want to write my own "Iterator" (java language). So instead of using "Set NewEnum = objPeople.[_NewEnum]" I want to be able to write "Set NewEnum = new MyIterator: NewEnum.init(Me)" to create an Iterator/Enumeration so I can use foreach on my classes (ArrayLists, HashMaps ets) without having to use the Collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that it can be done, but it is ugly (requires and `IDL`, two `.BAS` modules and two `.cls` modules (one of which is your Collection Class module).
For full information see this link:

[Create Your Own "Super Collections" in VB](https://www.mvps.org/vbvision/Super_Collections.htm)

Good luck!  It seemed to complicated for what I needed to do, so for now I just iterate over the Collection object enumerator.

Comment: Wow, thanx a lot for this post! Yes, and even if it's quite ugly-hackish, it still is possible. Thats why I select your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 8):

The long and short of it is [you can't implement IUnknown](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VAX123/WO848428581.htm). The same goes for [Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748085/can-a-class-implement-the-collection-object). They're both Com objects that are unavailable for extension in VBA. You can [create custom collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379641/3198973) and do other [very cool iterable things](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60504/building-a-better-collection-enumerable-in-vba) though.

Comment: Thanx for all the input. Had seen those ideas myself, but none lead to the result I was hoping for: to get away from using Collection.

Comment: Nitpick for people coming from Google and looking to implement `IUnknown`: You can't __not__ implement `IUnknown` in VBA. It's the base COM interface. Every VBA class implements `IUnknown`. You can test this by using `TypeOf SomeClass Is IUnknown`