# Implement Python-like generator using custom enumerator in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, enums

In VBA, if you want an iterable `Range` object like in Python, you do something like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60504/146810). However that approach involves building the entire range in one go:

> ```
> Set mCollection = New Collection
> Dim i As Long
> For i = startValue To endValue
>     mCollection.Add i
> Next
> ```

...which is bad if you want to make a really big range, as it takes ages and a lot of memory to build that collection. That's what generators are for; they generate the next item in the sequence as you loop.

Now [if you want a class to be iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20194919/6609896), it has to return a `[_NewEnum]`, which is done with the `Set` keyword. That tells me that a `For...Each` loop only requires a *reference* to an `Enum`, since the `Set` keyword only assigns pointers to a returned variable, rather than the actual value.

That gives scope for a bit of juggling:

- `For...Each` (henceforth "the Iterator") requires bit of memory that gives directions to the supplied `[_NewEnum]`; a reference to the enum object's pointer
- A custom class can generate a `[_NewEnum]` pointer from an encapsulated collection whenever it wants
- Perhaps therefore, if the class knows where in memory the Iterator is looking for the enum pointer, it can overwrite that bit of memory with a pointer to a different enum object altogether.

In other words:

- In the first iteration of a `For...Each` loop, my class returns a *variable* whose value is the pointer to one Enum. The variable resides in memory at a location given by `VarPtr(theVariable)`
- The next iteration, I manually call a method of my class which generates a second Enum
- After that the method continues by overwriting the first enum object's pointer at the address given by the variable pointer, and replaces it with the `ObjPtr()` of the second enum.

If that theory is correct, then the `For Each` loop would now hold a reference to a different value for `[_NewEnum]`, so would do something different.

---

Here's how I tried to do it:

### The generator: `NumberRange` Class Module

Note: must be imported to preserve attributes.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "NumberRange"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Type TRange
    encapsulated As Collection
    isGenerator As Boolean
    currentCount As Long
    maxCount As Long
    currentEnum As IUnknown
End Type

Private this As TRange

Public Sub fullRange(ByVal count As Long)
    'generate whole thing at once
    Dim i As Long
    this.isGenerator = False
    For i = 1 To count
        this.encapsulated.Add i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub generatorRange(ByVal count As Long)
    'generate whole thing at once
    this.isGenerator = True
    this.currentCount = 1
    this.maxCount = count
    this.encapsulated.Add this.currentCount      'initial value for first enumeration
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    'Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set this.currentEnum = this.encapsulated.[_NewEnum]
    Set NewEnum = this.currentEnum
End Property

Public Sub generateNext()
'This method is what should overwrite the current variable 
    If this.isGenerator And this.currentCount < this.maxCount Then
        this.currentCount = this.currentCount + 1
        replaceVal this.encapsulated, this.currentCount
        updateObject VarPtr(this.currentEnum), this.encapsulated.[_NewEnum]
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, Description:="Method reserved for generators"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.encapsulated = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub replaceVal(ByRef col As Collection, ByVal newval As Long)
    If col.count Then
        col.Remove 1
    End If
    col.Add newval
End Sub
```

Contains a standard method for making the full thing in one go, or a generator method, to be used in conjunction with `generateNext` in the loop. Might be an off-by-one error in there but that's not important right now.

### Memory management helper module

These methods have only been tested on my 32 bit system. Might work on both though (with the conditional compilation).

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As Any, _
source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)

Public Sub updateObject(ByVal variableAddress As LongPtr, ByVal replacementObject As Variant)
    #If VBA7 And Win64 Then
        Const pointerLength As Byte = 8
    #Else
        Const pointerLength As Byte = 4
    #End If
    CopyMemory ByVal variableAddress, ObjPtr(replacementObject), pointerLength
End Sub
```

That last line is the important one; it says to copy the object pointer of the supplied object `ObjPtr(replacementObject)` to the location of a specific variable `ByVal variableAddress`, the `ByVal` here signalling that we're talking about the memory of the variable itself, not a reference to the variable. The fact that the variable already contains an object pointer doesn't matter

### Test code

```
Sub testGenerator()
    Dim g As New NumberRange
    g.generatorRange 10
    Dim val
    For Each val In g
        Debug.Print val
        g.generateNext
    Next val
End Sub
```

If it's working then this should print numbers 1 to 10. But right now it's getting out of the loop after one go.

So why isn't this working? I think I've followed all the steps I outlined. I think the memory updater is working as intended, but I'm not certain as I can't query the `ObjPtr()` of the enum which the Iterator is currently using. Perhaps `For...Each` just doesn't like being interrupted! Any thoughts on how to achieve the desired behaviour welcome!

Ps. Save often, watch out for crashes!

---

Bonus test method for the memory writer:

```
Public Sub testUpdater()
    'initialise
    Dim initialEnumeration As Object, newEnumeration As Object 'represent a [_NewEnum]
    Set initialEnumeration = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        initialEnumeration.Add i
    Next i

    'initialEnumeration pointers are what we want to change
    iterateObjPrinting "initialEnumeration at Start:", initialEnumeration

    'make some obvious change
    Set newEnumeration = initialEnumeration.Clone()
    newEnumeration(4) = 9
    iterateObjPrinting "newEnumeration before any copy:", newEnumeration

    'update the first one in place
    updateObject VarPtr(initialEnumeration), newEnumeration
    iterateObjPrinting "initialEnumeration after copy", initialEnumeration
End Sub

Private Sub iterateObjPrinting(ByVal message As String, ByVal obj As Variant)
    Dim val, result As String
    For Each val In obj
        result = result & " " & val
    Next val
    Debug.Print message, Trim(result)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How to fix it

A *seriously* 1337 hacker named [DEXWERX](http://www.vbforums.com/member.php?255623-DEXWERX) wrote up the [deep magic](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?854963-VB6-IEnumVARIANT-For-Each-support-without-a-typelib) in 2017.  I adapted [DEXWERX's code](https://github.com/dexwerx/VBWERX/blob/master/MEnumerator.bas) to this situation, and provide a working example here.  The pieces are:

- `MEnumerator`: A tweaked version of DEXWERX's code.  This makes an `IEnumVARIANT` by assembling it in memory from scratch!
- `IValueProvider`: A straight-VBA interface that your generator should implement.  The `IEnumVARIANT` created by `MEnumerator` will call methods on an `IValueProvider` instance to get the elements to return.
- `NumberRange`: The generator class, which implements `IValueProvider`.

Following are test code to paste into VBA, and the `cls` and `bas` files to import.

### Test code

I put this in `ThisDocument`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testNumberRange()
    Dim c As New NumberRange
    c.generatorTo 10

    Dim idx As Long: idx = 1
    Dim val

    For Each val In c
        Debug.Print val
        If idx > 100 Then Exit Sub   ' Just in case of infinite loops
        idx = idx + 1
    Next val
End Sub
```

### `IValueProvider.cls`

Save this to a file and import it into the VBA Editor.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IValueProvider"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
' IValueProvider: Provide values.
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

' Return True if there are more values
Public Function HasMore() As Boolean
End Function

' Return the next value
Public Function GetNext() As Variant
End Function
```

### `NumberRange.cls`

Save this to a file and import it into the VBA Editor.  Note that the `NewEnum` function now merely delegates to the `NewEnumerator` function in `MEnumerator`.  Instead of using a collection, this overrides the `IValueProvider_HasMore` and `IValueProvider_GetNext` methods for use by `MEnumerator`.

Also note that I made everything zero-based for consistency.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "NumberRange"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

' === The values we're actually going to return ===================
Implements IValueProvider

Private Type TRange
    isGenerator As Boolean
    currentCount As Long
    maxCount As Long
End Type

Private this As TRange

Private Function IValueProvider_GetNext() As Variant
    IValueProvider_GetNext = this.currentCount      'Or try Chr(65 + this.currentCount)
    this.currentCount = this.currentCount + 1
End Function

Private Function IValueProvider_HasMore() As Boolean
    IValueProvider_HasMore = this.isGenerator And (this.currentCount <= this.maxCount)
End Function

' === Public interface ============================================
Public Sub generatorTo(ByVal count As Long)
    this.isGenerator = True
    this.currentCount = 0
    this.maxCount = count - 1
End Sub

' === Enumeration support =========================================
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IEnumVARIANT
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    'Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = NewEnumerator(Me)
End Property

' === Internals ===================================================
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' If you needed to initialize `this`, you could do so here
End Sub
```

### `MEnumerator.bas`

Save this to a file and import it into the VBA Editor.  The `IEnumVARIANT_Next` calls the `IValueProvider` methods and forwards them to VBA.  The `NewEnumerator` method builds the `IEnumVARIANT`.

```
Attribute VB_Name = "MEnumerator"
' Modified by cxw from code by http://www.vbforums.com/member.php?255623-DEXWERX
' posted at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?854963-VB6-IEnumVARIANT-For-Each-support-without-a-typelib&p=5229095&viewfull=1#post5229095
' License: "Use it how you see fit." - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?854963-VB6-IEnumVARIANT-For-Each-support-without-a-typelib&p=5232689&viewfull=1#post5232689
' Explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261687/2877364

'
' MEnumerator.bas
'
' Implementation of IEnumVARIANT to support For Each in VB6
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Option Explicit

Private Type TENUMERATOR
    VTablePtr   As Long
    References  As Long
    Enumerable  As IValueProvider
    Index       As Long
End Type

Private Enum API
    NULL_ = 0
    S_OK = 0
    S_FALSE = 1
    E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
    E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
    E_POINTER = &H80004003
#If False Then
    Dim NULL_, S_OK, S_FALSE, E_NOTIMPL, E_NOINTERFACE, E_POINTER
#End If
End Enum

Private Declare Function FncPtr Lib "msvbvm60" Alias "VarPtr" (ByVal Address As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetMem4 Lib "msvbvm60" (Src As Any, Dst As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CopyBytesZero Lib "msvbvm60" Alias "__vbaCopyBytesZero" (ByVal Length As Long, Dst As Any, Src As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CoTaskMemAlloc Lib "ole32" (ByVal cb As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32" (ByVal pv As Long)
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByVal lpiid As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SysAllocStringByteLen Lib "oleaut32" (ByVal psz As Long, ByVal cblen As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VariantCopyToPtr Lib "oleaut32" Alias "VariantCopy" (ByVal pvargDest As Long, ByRef pvargSrc As Variant) As Long
Private Declare Function InterlockedIncrement Lib "kernel32" (ByRef Addend As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InterlockedDecrement Lib "kernel32" (ByRef Addend As Long) As Long

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function NewEnumerator(ByRef Enumerable As IValueProvider) As IEnumVARIANT
' Class Factory
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Static VTable(6) As Long
    If VTable(0) = NULL_ Then
        ' Setup the COM object's virtual table
        VTable(0) = FncPtr(AddressOf IUnknown_QueryInterface)
        VTable(1) = FncPtr(AddressOf IUnknown_AddRef)
        VTable(2) = FncPtr(AddressOf IUnknown_Release)
        VTable(3) = FncPtr(AddressOf IEnumVARIANT_Next)
        VTable(4) = FncPtr(AddressOf IEnumVARIANT_Skip)
        VTable(5) = FncPtr(AddressOf IEnumVARIANT_Reset)
        VTable(6) = FncPtr(AddressOf IEnumVARIANT_Clone)
    End If

    Dim this As TENUMERATOR
    With this
        ' Setup the COM object
        .VTablePtr = VarPtr(VTable(0))
        .References = 1
        Set .Enumerable = Enumerable
    End With

    ' Allocate a spot for it on the heap
    Dim pThis As Long
    pThis = CoTaskMemAlloc(LenB(this))
    If pThis Then
        ' CopyBytesZero is used to zero out the original
        ' .Enumerable reference, so that VB doesn't mess up the
        ' reference count, and free our enumerator out from under us
        CopyBytesZero LenB(this), ByVal pThis, this
        DeRef(VarPtr(NewEnumerator)) = pThis
    End If
End Function

Private Function RefToIID$(ByVal riid As Long)
    ' copies an IID referenced into a binary string
    Const IID_CB As Long = 16&  ' GUID/IID size in bytes
    DeRef(VarPtr(RefToIID)) = SysAllocStringByteLen(riid, IID_CB)
End Function

Private Function StrToIID$(ByRef iid As String)
    ' converts a string to an IID
    StrToIID = RefToIID$(NULL_)
    IIDFromString StrPtr(iid), StrPtr(StrToIID)
End Function

Private Function IID_IUnknown() As String
    Static iid As String
    If StrPtr(iid) = NULL_ Then _
        iid = StrToIID$("{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
    IID_IUnknown = iid
End Function

Private Function IID_IEnumVARIANT() As String
    Static iid As String
    If StrPtr(iid) = NULL_ Then _
        iid = StrToIID$("{00020404-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
    IID_IEnumVARIANT = iid
End Function

Private Function IUnknown_QueryInterface(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR, _
                                         ByVal riid As Long, _
                                         ByVal ppvObject As Long _
                                         ) As Long
    If ppvObject = NULL_ Then
        IUnknown_QueryInterface = E_POINTER
        Exit Function
    End If

    Select Case RefToIID$(riid)
        Case IID_IUnknown, IID_IEnumVARIANT
            DeRef(ppvObject) = VarPtr(this)
            IUnknown_AddRef this
            IUnknown_QueryInterface = S_OK
        Case Else
            IUnknown_QueryInterface = E_NOINTERFACE
    End Select
End Function

Private Function IUnknown_AddRef(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR) As Long
    IUnknown_AddRef = InterlockedIncrement(this.References)
End Function

Private Function IUnknown_Release(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR) As Long
    IUnknown_Release = InterlockedDecrement(this.References)
    If IUnknown_Release = 0& Then
        Set this.Enumerable = Nothing
        CoTaskMemFree VarPtr(this)
    End If
End Function

Private Function IEnumVARIANT_Next(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR, _
                                   ByVal celt As Long, _
                                   ByVal rgVar As Long, _
                                   ByRef pceltFetched As Long _
                                   ) As Long

    Const VARIANT_CB As Long = 16 ' VARIANT size in bytes

    If rgVar = NULL_ Then
        IEnumVARIANT_Next = E_POINTER
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim Fetched As Long
    Fetched = 0
    Dim element As Variant

    With this
        Do While this.Enumerable.HasMore
            element = .Enumerable.GetNext
            VariantCopyToPtr rgVar, element
            Fetched = Fetched + 1&
            If Fetched = celt Then Exit Do
            rgVar = PtrAdd(rgVar, VARIANT_CB)
        Loop
    End With

    If VarPtr(pceltFetched) Then pceltFetched = Fetched
    If Fetched < celt Then IEnumVARIANT_Next = S_FALSE
End Function

Private Function IEnumVARIANT_Skip(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR, ByVal celt As Long) As Long
    IEnumVARIANT_Skip = E_NOTIMPL
End Function

Private Function IEnumVARIANT_Reset(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR) As Long
    IEnumVARIANT_Reset = E_NOTIMPL
End Function

Private Function IEnumVARIANT_Clone(ByRef this As TENUMERATOR, ByVal ppEnum As Long) As Long
    IEnumVARIANT_Clone = E_NOTIMPL
End Function

Private Function PtrAdd(ByVal Pointer As Long, ByVal Offset As Long) As Long
    Const SIGN_BIT As Long = &H80000000
    PtrAdd = (Pointer Xor SIGN_BIT) + Offset Xor SIGN_BIT
End Function

Private Property Let DeRef(ByVal Address As Long, ByVal Value As Long)
    GetMem4 Value, ByVal Address
End Property
```

## Original answer: why the existing code doesn't work

<s>I can't tell you how to fix it, but</s> I can tell you why.  This is too long for a comment :) .

You are exporting a `Collection` enumerator for your own use.  The straight-`Collection` version of `testGenerator` has the same behaviour:

```
Option Explicit
Sub testCollection()
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim idx As Long: idx = 1
    Dim val
    c.Add idx
    For Each val In c
        Debug.Print val
        c.Add idx

        If idx > 100 Then Exit Sub    ' deadman, to break an infinite loop if it starts working!
        idx = idx + 1
    Next val
End Sub
```

This code prints `1` and then exits the `For Each` loop.

I believe the `updateObject` call is not doing what you expect.  The following is based on my own knowledge, and also [this forum post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?807263-VB6-LightWeight-COM-and-vbFriendly-BaseInterfaces&p=4951387&viewfull=1#post4951387).  When the `For Each` loop begins, VBA gets an `IUnknown` from `_NewEnum`.  VBA then calls `QueryInterface` on the `IUnknown` to get its own `IEnumVARIANT` pointer into the single, reference-counted enumerator object.  As a result, the `For Each` has its own copy of the enumerator.

Then, when you call `updateObject`, it changes the contents of `this.currentEnum`.  However, that is not where the `For Each` loop is actually looking.  As a result, `replaceVal()` is modifying a collection while it is being iterated over.  The [VB.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) have something to say on this subject.  I suspect the behaviour of VB.NET was inherited from VBA, since it matches what you are seeing.  Specifically:

> The enumerator object returned by `GetEnumerator` [of `System.Collections.IEnumerable`] normally doesn't let you change the collection by adding, deleting, replacing, or reordering any elements. If you change the collection after you have initiated a `For Each...Next` loop, the enumerator object becomes invalid ...

Therefore, you may have to roll your own `IEnumerator` implementation rather than reusing that from `Collection`.

**Edit** I found [this link](http://www.vtsoftware.co.uk/tools/enumeration.htm) suggesting that you need to implement `IEnumVARIANT`, which VBA won't do natively (**edit** but can be made to do, as shown above!).  I haven't tried the information at that link myself, but pass it along in case it's helpful.

Comment: I wish I hadn't already upvoted this answer... FWIW `IUnknown` is restricted, and cannot *normally* be implemented in VB6/VBA (it lists 0 members in the object browser). This code is *wicked*.

Comment: Blimey, a bit more involved than I'd first thought! FWIW I did a speed comparison on a couple of computers for generating up to 10,000,000 digits. The old method typically spent half the time creating the range, half the time looping. This generator spends negligible time creating the range (as intended), but overall takes about 1/2-1 order of magnitude longer overall ([results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5UaG.png)).

Comment: Oh, and if anyone wants to fiddle around with @cwx's code, I've put it all in a single [self extracting module](https://github.com/Greedquest/CodeReviewFiles/blob/c729b470d7d7eb2884c18263b87531a0fc894ea7/EnumeratorZip.bas) to save having to import files individually (just copy into a standard module and run the `.Extract` method). Includes the test code but you'll need a reference to [Toolbox.xlam](https://github.com/Greedquest/VBA-Toolbox/blob/master/Toolbox.xlam?raw=true) for the stopwatch _(Full disclosure: I'm the creator of that addin)_

Comment: @Greedo interesting!  I left `HasMore` and `GetNext` separate so there would be no restrictions on the return value of `GetNext`.  However, for a possible speedup, you could update `GetNext` to return a flag value at the end of the sequence.  Then `IEnumVARIANT_Next` would only have to make one call back to VBA instead of two.

Comment: @Greedo Did this answer the question to your satisfaction?

Comment: @cxw Yes of course, thanks! Although I'm very new to all these memory moving APIs, so I'm not sure how to implement the change you suggest in your last comment. If I understand correctly, it is a matter of changing the while loop to remove the `HasMore` check and replace it with a check on what the `.Enumerable.GetNext` is returning (i.e. a flag). Or are you talking about somehow reducing the number of expensive variant coercions?

Comment: @Greedo Yes, the former is what I was thinking of.  If you try it and have problems, please feel free to post a separate question and drop me a line here.

Comment: @cwx Just for a few more stats, making the change you suggested by returning `Empty` as a flag instead of using `HasMore` results in [no noticeable speed increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNlk0.jpg) (note log scale and there're some error bars too). The generator consistently remains around [1 order of magnitude slower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/torj6.jpg) than the collection. However beyond 10^8 iterations, the memory usage of the collection triggers Windows to close Excel, of course the generator has no such issues.